Swift Playgrounds stopped working on my Mac after downloading Xcode 16.2 Beta 2
I'm unable to run Playgrounds since I downloaded and installed Xcode 16.2 Beta 2. I was on Xcode 16.1 before.
The Playgrounds always crash when I try to build them, even when I create a brand new one and add no code at all. This is the message I'm getting:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to load bounding path bitmap data from the asset manager for asset name: BoundingPathBitmap-2048x2732-1024x1366-2.00x'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b94fc __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180092da8 objc_exception_throw + 72
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000180e62f10 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001856f1ab0 -[_UIScreenComplexBoundingPathUtilities _loadBitmapForScreen:type:] + 788
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001856f0588 -[_UIScreenComplexBoundingPathUtilities initWithScreen:] + 128
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001856fb2ec +[_UIScreenBoundingPathUtilities boundingPathUtilitiesForScreen:] + 80
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001857062f0 -[UIScreen _boundingPathUtilities] + 40
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b6fadc -[UIWindow _boundingPath] + 140
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001860a0090 -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupportInternal) _effectiveBoundingPathAndBoundingPathView:] + 176
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000018609f8fc -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupport) _rectTuckedAgainstBoundingPathEdge:withSize:cornerRadii:minimumPadding:] + 228
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d7c94 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _unsafeInsets] + 116
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d7e64 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _marginsWhenFloating] + 132
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d8768 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _isEdgeAttached] + 40
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d95d0 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _effectiveAppearance] + 52
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d9ea8 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _activeDetents] + 224
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d9684 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _offsetForCurrentActiveDetent] + 36
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852db278 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView] + 88
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852db3d8 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _hostedFrameOfPresentedViewInContainerView] + 44
    18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185df2118 -[UISheetPresentationController _containerViewLayoutSubviews] + 580
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000186064a5c -[UITransitionView layoutSubviews] + 68
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000018609b410 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2404
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000018b3b8b28 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 432
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000018608c294 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 308
    23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185df0450 -[UISheetPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 1152
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852cdd78 __80-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:inWindow:]_block_invoke + 1932
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852cbe70 __77-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentStateAnimated:handoffData:]_block_invoke_3 + 296
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852d1298 +[UIPresentationController _scheduleTransition:] + 72
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852cbaf8 -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentStateAnimated:handoffData:] + 1856
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001852c95a8 -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:inWindow:interactionController:animated:handoffData:] + 560
    29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b61360 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 356
    30  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b60cb4 -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 168
    31  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b61b00 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 228
    32  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b70bf8 -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 36
    33  Prove                               0x0000000102b182e0 -[XCPSceneDelegate scene:willConnectToSession:options:] + 360
    34  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184f77b88 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1012
    35  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b2c954 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 808
    36  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b2cc04 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 304
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00000001855f5338 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 260
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187ac8740 __95-[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:alternativeCreationCallout:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187ac8b00 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_coalesceClientSettingsUpdates:] + 60
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187ac85c0 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:alternativeCreationCallout:completion:] + 408
    41  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187af59e0 __93-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _callOutQueue_sendDidCreateForScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.156 + 216
    42  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187ad5074 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 160
    43  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187af3eb0 -[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _callOutQueue_sendDidCreateForScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 388
    44  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018017cc08 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    45  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000180180b2c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 376
    46  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187b187f4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 44
    47  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187b186d0 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 196
    48  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000187b18828 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041d744 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041d68c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 172
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041ce4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 324
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180417334 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180416ba4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
    54  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000190aadb10 GSEventRunModal + 160
    55  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b2b038 -[UIApplication _run] + 796
    56  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185b2f230 UIApplicationMain + 124
    57  Prove                               0x0000000102b16934 main + 344
    58  dyld                                0x0000000102b75410 start_sim + 20
    59  ???                                 0x0000000102cc6154 0x0 + 4341915988
    60  ???                                 0x7473000000000000 0x0 + 8391050530721366016
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Also, I'm seeing this into Xcode console:
warning: (arm64) /Users/angelosannino/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/BDE44C41-E362-4362-977C-9A6C08DA232F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FEB8361B-663B-4A60-8FA6-5DECB6453DBD/Prove-35177-1.app/Prove(0x0000000102b10000) address 0x0000000102b10000 maps to more than one section: Prove.__TEXT and Prove.__TEXTwarning: (arm64) /Users/angelosannino/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/BDE44C41-E362-4362-977C-9A6C08DA232F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FEB8361B-663B-4A60-8FA6-5DECB6453DBD/Prove-35177-1.app/Prove(0x0000000102b10000) address 0x0000000102b1c000 maps to more than one section: Prove.__DATA_CONST and Prove.__DATA_CONSTwarning: (arm64) /Users/angelosannino/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices/BDE44C41-E362-4362-977C-9A6C08DA232F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FEB8361B-663B-4A60-8FA6-5DECB6453DBD/Prove-35177-1.app/Prove(0x0000000102b10000) address 0x0000000102b20000 maps to more than one section: Prove.__DATA and Prove.__DATA

What I have tried to sort this so far:

Uninstall Xcode and Simulators completely, and download and re-install from scratch
Clean Derived Data
Clean XCPGDevices folder
Clean CoreDevice and CoreSimulator folders
Clean UserData folder
Actually, remove the whole Developer directory and let Xcode recreate everything
Clean /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode directory
Clean /Library/Caches/com.apple.dy.xcodebuild directory

Nothing of the above worked, unfortunately.
Anyone got any idea on how to sort this?

It's probably a good idea to report this issue directly to Apple via: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Seems to be fixed with Xcode 16.2 Beta 3 (16C5023f). I just installed the new beta and downloaded the most recent iOS Simulator (18.2 beta 4). After that I deleted the old Xcode beta. Now my playgrounds work again.

Xcode 16.2 Beta 3 sorted it for me as well

I have encountered the same issue, most probably it's a bug in Xcode 16.2 Beta 2. For me, the issue persisted even after downgrading to Xcode 16.1, but I was able to resolve it with the following steps:

Delete Xcode 16.2 Beta 2
Install Xcode 16.1, set it as Command Line Tools in Xcode/Settings/Locations, and close it
Run the following commands in the terminal:


xcrun simctl delete all
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ Device\ Logs
rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
sudo rm -fr /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator


Restart your machine
Open Xcode and install iOS 18.1 Simulator in Xcode/Settings/Components
Restart Xcode

After the above steps, the playground started working properly again for me.

Also got the same problem after downloading XCode 16.2 beta.
For now nothing works. Tried with Karol's method, but it still persist.
